# How could I change this addEventListener to a button click

Tags: javascript

So I have this search json javascript which matches the result to what you type and it does it automatically. These lines are what does that (below). Is there any way to change it to only work when a button is pressed?

```
const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

searchInput.addEventListener('change', displayMatches);
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayMatches);
```

this is the function -

```
 function displayMatches() {
    const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, name);  
    const html = matchArray.map(place => {
        const regex = new RegExp(this.value);
        const nameName = place.name.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
        return `
        <a href="${place.url}" target="_blank">
            <li>
                <span class="name">${nameName} <br> ${(place.price)}</span> 
                <img src="${place.imgurl}" alt="Drink Image" height="87.5" width="100">
            </li>
        </a>
        `;
    }).join('');
    suggestions.innerHTML = html;
}
```

All Current Code Below :

```
const endpoint = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/valeriu7474/4df04fafd994c2f778847a3e94451b44/raw/d288ddbc9cbc8bbcf89a10f2a8ead9eecb4962f6/allcurrentshops";

const name = [];
fetch(endpoint).then(blob => blob.json())
.then(data => name.push(...data));

    function findMatches(wordToMatch, name) {
        return name.filter(place => {
            //we need to figure out if the name match
            const regEx = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
            return place.name.match(regEx);
        });
    }

//   function displayMatches() {
//      const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, name);  
//      const html = matchArray.map(place => {
//          const regex = new RegExp(this.value);
//          const nameName = place.name.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
//          return `
//          <a href="${place.url}" target="_blank">
//              <li>
//                  <span class="name">${nameName} <br> ${(place.price)}</span> 
//                  <img src="${place.imgurl}" alt="Drink Image" height="87.5" width="100">
//              </li>
//          </a>
//          `;
//      }).join('');
//      suggestions.innerHTML = html;
//  }

function displayMatches() {
    const searchText = document.querySelector('.search');
    const matchArray = findMatches(searchText, name); 
    const html = matchArray.map(place => { 
        const regex = new RegExp(searchText); 
        const nameName = place.name.replace(regex, <span class="hl">${searchText}</span>);
    return ` <a href="${place.url}" target="_blank"> <li> <span class="name">${nameName} <br> ${(place.price)}</span> <img src="${place.imgurl}" alt="Drink Image" height="87.5" width="100"> </li> </a> `; }).join(''); suggestions.innerHTML = html; 
}

//  const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
//  const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

    const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-search');
    searchBtn.addEventListener('click', displayMatches);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the eventlisteners from the `.search` field, and add a button.

```js
const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.searchBtn');
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', displayMatches);
```

**Edit:**
If I'm interpreting the function correctly update `displayMatches` with a new variable for the search text entered.

```js
function displayMatches() {
    const searchText = document.querySelector('.search').value;
    const matchArray = findMatches(searchText, name); 
    const html = matchArray.map(place => { 
        const regex = new RegExp(searchText); 
        const nameName = place.name.replace(regex, <span class="hl">${searchText}</span>);
        return ` <a href="${place.url}" target="_blank"> <li> <span class="name">${nameName} <br> ${(place.price)}</span> <img src="${place.imgurl}" alt="Drink Image" height="87.5" width="100"> </li> </a> `; 
    }).join(''); 
    suggestions.innerHTML = html; 
}
```

Comment: It works to where it will display results but not matching to what is typed.

Comment: @valeriu7474 Add the `displayMatches` function to your question so we can help you figure it out.

Comment: Ahhh. Since the `.search` input is no longer what is triggering the event, `this` is no longer bound to it. You need a variable for that field value. See my edit.